# SharePoint_Config_log.ldf size is too big

Tags: configuration

I have an environment where I stopped having enough disk space, while checking the huge folder sizes in my server, I noticed SharePoint_Config_log.ldf reached 17GB. Do I just delete it? How to deal with this situation later to avoid having it reach this point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DB log file can be shrinked from within SQL Server Management Studio.
In order to do that please follow the instructions in this post:

**[Update: link is broken]**
http://www.sharepointboris.net/2008/10/sharepoint-config-database-log-file-too-big-reduce-it/

**[Updated since the link is broken]**

> 1. If you don’t have it yet, download and install SQL Server Management Studio express from here.
> 2. Run the Management Studio and connect to your SQL Server.
> 3. Expand “Databases” and select your config database “SharePoint_Config”.
> 4. Right Click it, select Tasks –> Shrink –> Files
> 5. In the new window select Release unused space and click OK.
>
> If that doesn’t decrease the database size much, do the following:
>
> 1. First to be on the safe side, let’s back it up (this step is optional)
>
> Select New Query and type the following:
>
> `BACKUP LOG [Sharepoint_Config] TO DISK=’D:configLogBackup.bak’
>   GO`
>
> where SharePoint_Config is the name of your config database file and `D:configlogbackup.bak` is the location and file name of where you’ll make the backup.
>
> Click Execute
>
> This may take a while if your log file is big.
>
> 2. Next clear the query (or click New Query again) and enter the following commands
>      `BACKUP LOG [Sharepoint_Config] WITH TRUNCATE_ONLY
>      USE [SharePoint_Config]
>      GO`
>
> Click Execute again
>
> 3. Clear the query or open another query tab and enter the next command:
>
> `DBCC SHRINKFILE (N’SharePoint_Config_log’ , 50)
>   GO`
>
> The 50 in the command above sets the size in MB to truncate the log to. If your config db is of different name, replace the SharePoint_Config part above with your config db name.
>
> Click Execute

The quoted text is an extract from the original link reference.

Comment: If I delete it, will it be created again? will that affect anything?

Comment: The .ldf file is a log file that stores the transactions occured in SQL. Your problem is a very common one; shrinking the file should be safe. If you want more information you can check this blog to make sure this procedure is compliant with your company's policies. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826789/what-is-the-ldf-file-in-sql-server

Comment: http://www.sharepointboris.net/2008/10/sharepoint-config-database-log-file-too-big-reduce-it/ is down. Use http://web.archive.org/web/20170426172002/http://www.sharepointboris.net/2008/10/sharepoint-config-database-log-file-too-big-reduce-it/ instead.

Comment: Guys please at least write a concise description of the link's content.

Comment: @LeonidasFett thanks for the heads up. Found the original contents on http://web.archive.org/web/20180217122855/http://www.sharepointboris.net/2008/10/sharepoint-config-database-log-file-too-big-reduce-it/ and pasted that for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

The script in the following article worked for me.

http://www.qdoscc.com/blog/sharepoint-tips-sharepointconfiglogldf-file-size-massive#comment-112